# Story about a carnival where people wear animal heads, then get addicted / zombified

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I read this pretty recently (late 2017 to early 2018) and have been trying to find it again, with absolutely no success. Details I remember:

- city has an annual festival/carnival thing, where at a ceremony (maybe a concert/show?) volunteers are called up from the crowd and a hollowed-out animal head is placed over their own like a mask
- set roughly in the present day, possibly in England
- protagonist is the girlfriend of one of the volunteers
- after the festival, the people who wore the heads have check-ups at a lab where the heads get put back on them for some kind of testing
- eventually, three of the people disappear, along with their corresponding animal heads, and it’s revealed that they had been breaking into the lab and illicitly putting the heads on
- the protagonist tries to track down her boyfriend by talking to a woman connected to one of the other animal-head-people
- the heads, when removed, have some kind of worm/larva things inside them, and leave sucker-like marks on the person’s skin underneath

That’s about all the details I can think of—does this ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: Do you know when you read it? Some people's pretty recently is yesterday and for others it's 15 years ago. A year/range of years would help narrow down the answer.

Comment: It was in the last year, probably within the last six months. Not sure when it was published, though I *think* I was reading it shortly after publication.

Comment: I see, a person with a reasonable sense of the word recently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"[After the Festival](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1878856)" by China Miéville

> a Wicker-Man-meets-“The-Lottery” horrorshow about the insatiable
> evolutionary rush brought on by a strange ritual involving the donning
> of freshly severed animal heads.

https://www.barnesandnoble.com/blog/sci-fi-fantasy/three-moments-of-an-explosion-offers-potent-bites-of-fantastical-horror/

Reviewers on Goodreads mention

> Medieval-esque ritual into an otherwise normal world

and

> worms burrowing from those heads into the flesh of the people beneath,
> revealing the animal within the human condition, and the craving those
> people have for those heads.

https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1263654686?book_show_action=false
https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1331800237?book_show_action=false

Comment: That’s the one! Thank you—I read it in *Three Moments of an Explosion* but couldn’t connect it back to that.